# Content Element bound to property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to have a window with a `<Menu>` element in it bound to a dependencyProperty:

Here is my Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="attachement.xWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu/>
        <ToolBarTray x:Name="ToolBarTray" Grid.Row="1">
        </ToolBarTray>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
public partial class xWindow : Window
{

    public Menu Menu
    {
        get { return (Menu)GetValue(MenuProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MenuProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Menu", typeof(Menu), typeof(xWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    public xWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

now my question is: how can I bind the `<Menu>` element in my xaml to the dependency property in code behind so that when I do "myXwindow.Menu = new Menu(){...};" the menu is updated in the window?

thanks

NB: I tried setting the xaml like this : `<Menu x:Name="Menu">` and remove the dp in c# so taht I could access directly the Menu defined in xaml, wich seems to work (no build or run error) but does not allow me to set it anew after the window has been displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `Menu` in some other control

```
<ContentControl x:Name="_menuContainer">
    <Menu/>
</ContentControl>
```

And then write your property like this:

```
public Menu Menu
{
    get { return (Menu)_menuContainer.Content; }
    set { _menuContainer.Content = value; }
}
```

Comment: yes, I am actually already doing this, but I was hoping for a solution that did not involve a wrapping container (I'm a minimalist). Seems not to be possible though...

Comment: It is possible. You'll just need to remove old/add new `Menu` to your `Grid` in property setter. But I think it will cause more problems, then benefits.